# Openshift -> node js , failed to start port 8080

Tags: node.js, openshift

I noticed a very weird thing , well the error is failed to start , port 8080, 
my code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-Parser');  //comment this line
var morgan=require('morgan');           //comment this line
var app = express();
var http = require('http');             //comment this line

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));  //comment this line
app.use(bodyParser.json());                       //comment this line
app.use(morgan('dev'));                           //comment this line


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT;
if(typeof ipaddress === "undefined"){
ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port, ipaddress, function() {
// Do your stuff
console.log("Your server is running on: "+ipaddress+" port:"+port);
});
```

This code is giving me error -> unable to start at port 8080, but WHEN I COMMENT OUT the packages body-parser and morgan it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot, i was doing a silly mistake all the time and ignoring it all the time , i looked into the logs it says --> 'body-Parser' the 'P' is 'Parser' should be in small case !!! that's it. Thanks for everyone who tried to help me 
just make sure you write correct npm package it is case sensitive like 
--> var bodyParser=require('body-parser') <--